# Change the alignment of Rich text Box in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

How to change the vertical and horizontal alignment of RichText box. i have tried all the api's horizontalalignment and vertical alignment. but nothing works.

Comment: Also tried Horizontal and Vertical content alignment even that didnt works

Comment: ten seconds of google : http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/337491/How-to-right-align-text-in-a-RichTextBox

Answer (score 4):

For horizontal alignment of RichTextBox, you could change it by `FlowDocument`'s property `TextAlignment`.

Example:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="richTextBox"  Height="30"  >
     <FlowDocument TextAlignment="Center">
          <Paragraph>
               <Run Text="RichTextBox"/>
           </Paragraph>
     </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

Answer (score 3):

This property returns the current alignment. Setting this property adjusts the contents of the RichTextBox to reflect the specified alignment.

```
<!--Create a RichTextBox and a Button.-->
   <StackPanel>
   <RichTextBox x:Name="MyRTB" Height="100" Width="400" />
   <Button x:Name="MyButton1" Content="Right-Align" Height="30" Width="100" Click="button_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

Right-align the content in RichTextBox on clicking the button.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BlockCollection MyBC = MyRTB.Blocks;
    foreach (Block b in MyBC)
        b.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right;               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are called `EditingCommands`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.editingcommands?view=netframework-4.8

```
EditingCommands.AlignLeft.Execute(null, richTextBox);
//or
EditingCommands.AlignRight.Execute(null, richTextBox);
```

You can find all kinds of text editing commands here.